# docker-compose: failed to read dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I create a 'docker' folder inside my php web app source code.

I placed a docker-composer.yml and a Dockerfile inside /docker

```
<project_root>
   - app
   - bootstrap
   ....
   - docker 
     - docker-compose.yml
     - Dockerfile
   .....
   - storage
```

So insider docker-composer.yml I am trying to do this

```
version: '3.9'
services:

    app:
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        image: my-custom-app-docker-image
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/app
            - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
        networks:
             - app-network
```

The problem is that: running docker-composer up I got

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount61239487/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found, and fixed

I add a second dot to build.context

```
app:
    build:
        context: ..
```

changing third line to

```
        context: .
```

worked